# How to make Searchkick/Elasticsearch where clause case insensitive?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm using `ElasticSearch` with Ruby (`Searchkick`). At the moment, by default the where filter is a case sensitive.

I'm using ElasticSearch with my `EquityContract` model, so once I search for `Food` I get different results to search for `food`.

```
    [21] pry(main)> EquityContract.search('*', {:load=>false, :where=>{:industry=>"FOOD"}, limit:1})
effective_url=http://127.0.0.1:9200/equity_contracts_development/_search response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.002279
      EquityContract Search (5.9ms)  curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/equity_contracts_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":[{"term":{"industry":"FOOD"}}]}}},"size":1,"from":0}'
    => #<Searchkick::Results:0x0000010b65c5c8
     @klass=
      EquityContract(id: integer, ticker: text, name: string, country: string, currency: string, instrument: string),
     @options=
      {:page=>1,
       :per_page=>1,
       :padding=>0,
       :load=>false,
       :includes=>nil,
       :json=>false,
       :match_suffix=>"analyzed",
       :highlighted_fields=>[]},
     @response=
      {"took"=>1,
       "timed_out"=>false,
       "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0},
       "hits"=>{"total"=>0, "max_score"=>nil, "hits"=>[]}}>
```

While I get some results when I do the same with `Food`:

```
[23] pry(main)> EquityContract.search('*', {:load=>false, :where=>{:industry=>"Food"}, limit:1})
ETHON: performed EASY effective_url=http://127.0.0.1:9200/equity_contracts_development/_search response_code=200 return_code=ok total_time=0.002795
  EquityContract Search (7.5ms)  curl http://127.0.0.1:9200/equity_contracts_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"and":[{"term":{"industry":"Food"}}]}}},"size":1,"from":0}'
=> #<Searchkick::Results:0x000001112d1880
 @klass=
  EquityContract(id: integer, ticker: text, name: string, country: string, currency: string, instrument: string),
 @options=
  {:page=>1,
   :per_page=>1,
   :padding=>0,
   :load=>false,
   :includes=>nil,
   :json=>false,
   :match_suffix=>"analyzed",
   :highlighted_fields=>[]},
 @response=
  {"took"=>1,
   "timed_out"=>false,
   "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "failed"=>0},
   "hits"=>
    {"total"=>73,
     "max_score"=>1.0,
     "hits"=>
      [{"_index"=>"equity_contracts_development_20160320195353552",
        "_type"=>"equity_contract",
        "_id"=>"1181",
        "_score"=>1.0,
        "_source"=>
         {"name"=>"Some name",
          "ticker"=>"some ticker",
          "country"=>"SA",
```

How can I change this to make it more case-insensitive so I'll het the same results for both?

Comment: It depends on the mapping you have for that field `industry`. `term` will match **exactly** a term in the ES index, so it matters what you index and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw Searchkiq generates **term query**, but what you need is a **full-text query**. I'm not familiar with Searchkiq so I can't tell you how.

According to [the documentation on ElasticSearch official website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/term-vs-full-text.html),

### Term query

> Queries like the `term` or `fuzz` queries are low-level queries that have no analysis phase. They operate on a single term. A term query for the term *Foo* looks for that exact term in the inverted index and calculates the TF/IDF relevance `_score` for each document that contains the term.

### Full-text query

> Queries like the `match` or `query_string` queries are high-level queries that understand the mapping of a field ... If you query a full-text (analyzed) field, they will first pass the query string through the appropriate analyzer to produce the list of terms to be queried.

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help @Aetherus. Is there any way to handle term query in a way that I can filter the results?

Comment: I think you can downcase the data before storing it to ES, and downcase the query before searching.

Comment: I think that could be some good work around. Let me try it out

Comment: Can you add the workaround you suggested with your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @EkiEqbal where you able to make it work? I am facing the same issue. I tried using where: {name: /.*partial_name.*/i} where /i is to make regex case insensititve but this does not work in my case